# Plotly change color of points in scatter plot with legend

Tags: python, plot, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a scatter plot with some points, and I would like to apply a coloring scheme on them depending on the legend. Consider the following code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random as rd

x = rd.sample(range(1, 30), 29)
y = rd.sample(range(1, 30), 29)

c1 = rd.sample(range(1, 30), 29)
c2 = rd.sample(range(1, 30), 29)
c3 = rd.sample(range(1, 30), 29)
c4 = rd.sample(range(1, 30), 29)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers',
                         marker_color=c1,
                         name='Plot',
                         ))  
fig.show()
```

Here, the coloring scheme is `c1`. I would like to have a legend with all `c1`, `c2`, `c3` and `c4` options and the points will color in accordance to what is clicked in the legend. How can I achieve this?
P.S it would be best for me to use plotly.graph_objects :)

Comment: I will appreciate any help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to change the color from clicking on the legend. You may be able to change the color by clicking on a button. See this for more [information](https://plotly.com/python/custom-buttons/#restyle-button).

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the help! Could you help me build this with my example? I am facing some difficulties, because in the tutorial, they have a heatmap which is passed a dataframe and they set the color with the column name in the dataframe, this is not possible with the Scatter since it does not accept dataframe. I would appreciate help! :)

Comment: Actually, I managed to do it myself, finally. thanks for your direction, ! :)

Comment: IF you make an answer, I will upvote and accept as answer! :)

Comment: More importantly, I think it's worth it to your SO for you to self-answer. I'll give you a +1 if you post it.